# Module initialization error while connecting to Redshift using Lambda and psycopg2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

Getting below error when I'm trying to connect the redshift cluster.

I have imported all the libraries for running the python code on my lambda.
Running the Python Code it gives an error.

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import psycopg2
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import sys
import hashlib
import urllib
import platform


def lambda_test():
    print('hello')
    conn_string = "dbname='dev' port='5439' user='my-user' password='my-password' host='redshift-cluster-1.calcocahphdx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439'"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

lambda_test()
```

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "module initialization error"
}

Request ID:
"e9a8c853-f0d0-486c-8210-5c39fb7f660b"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: e9a8c853-f0d0-486c-8210-5c39fb7f660b Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: could not translate host name "redshift-cluster-1.calcocahphdx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439" to address: Name or service not known


END RequestId: e9a8c853-f0d0-486c-8210-5c39fb7f660b
REPORT RequestId: e9a8c853-f0d0-486c-8210-5c39fb7f660b  Duration: 510.13 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 61 MB  
module initialization error
could not translate host name "redshift-cluster-1.calcocahphdx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439" to address: Name or service not known
```

Comment: you might want to edit out your host/user/password from that

Comment: all details are related to my cluster only

Comment: Is the Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is it the same VPC as the Redshift instance?

Comment: @johnRotenstein Thanks Issue is resolved.
I can connect to my redshift cluster.
There  is just one concern, now i have added s3 as trigger to lambda.
there is one option as prefix , does that belong to path in S3 bucket or prefix of the file name

Comment: If you are referring to the Prefix option when configuring an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function, then it allows you to specify the directory (path) of the files that should trigger the function. For example, if the Prefix is set to `incoming/` and an object is created with a Key of `incoming/foo.txt`, then the event will be triggered. However, an object with a key of `invoices/foo.txt` would _not_ trigger the event because it does not match the Prefix.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks 
Just to confirm if i have a a bucket with name invoices and it have folder as payable.
then in prefix i need to add payable/*.txt or only payable/

Comment: That is correct. The bucket name is _not_ involved in the prefix. I'm not sure whether you can use a wildcard within the prefix (`payable/*.txt`). Instead, specify the prefix as `payable/` and a suffix of `.txt`.